# How to show retrieved data from firebase in html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

How to show the data retrieved from firebase in a  container.

this is my code

```
var dbBlogs = fiebase.database.ref("users").child("blogs").orderByChild("time");
dbBlogs.on("value", function(blogs){
    if (blogs.exists())
    {
        var container = "";

    blogs.forEach(function(singleBlog){
        var mDesc = singleBlog.val().desc;
        var mTime = singleBlog.val().time;
        var mDate= singleBlog.val().date;

        container += "<div class='jumbotron bg-light text-dark border border-dark'>";

        container += "<div class='row'>";

        container += "<div class='col-sm-5'> <p style='color:grey;>"


           +"Desc: " + mDesc;
           +"Date" + mTime;
           +"time" + mDate;
           + "</p> </div>";

            container += "/div>";
        container += "/div>";

    });

    $("blogs").html(container);

    }


});
```

this is my database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMNLu.png)

Please can anyone help me, I am new

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  You need to be more specific about what problem you are running into (e.g. what error are you getting, what output are you looking for).  Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and in particular please create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  But, to start, you misspelled `firebase` as `fiebase` in the very first line of this code.

Comment: I also recommend you take a look at the [firebase web codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0) which covers basic usage of firestore to render inside of a web app, among many other features for firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what i want to do it get data from firebase and display it like a post on my webpage

Comment: I also want to add option to get comments on my post

Comment: Thats not really specific enough to get you a useful answer (e.g. it is still not clear what the actual thing is that isn't working) -- _much_ more specific detail is needed.  Please read the above links, especially the codelab which does cover displaying data retrieved from firestore in a web page.

Comment: i am not able to see the retrieved data, so i am not sure if the code it correct